# Metodo me retorna como valor nulo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quando crio meu código abaixo, ele me retorna essa mensagem de erro, dizendo que meu método é indefinido para `nil` `(undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass)`

Código:

```
<ul>
  <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li> 
  <%end%>
</ul>

<%=form_for @task do |f|%>
    <%=f.label :description, 'Descrição'%>
    <%=f.text_field :description%>
    <%=f.label :status, 'Status'%>
    <%=f.check_box :status%>
    <%=f.submit 'Criar'%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Sem problemas !! Valeu

Answer (score 0):

No controller, você deve ter uma *action* apontando para essa view. Lá na action, `@task` precisa ser instanciado. Veja:

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
end
```

Comment: Tenho uma Tasks_Controller criada. Dentro do <ul> acrescentei a seguinte linha  <% if @task.is_a?(Task) && !@task.errors.fullmessages.empty? %>
e no meu form_for deixei como Tasks.new do e funcionou !!